# Angular/material ui - programatically select mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a mat-selection-list that I need to programmatically check specific items when the component loads. The items I need to check will be selected based on the [value] of the mat-list-option. I can't find any documentation on this. The html is pretty simple:

```
<mat-selection-list color="primary" #suretyList formControlName="AgentAgencyAndSureties">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let surety of suretyNames" [value]="surety.Id">
        {{surety.SuretyName}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

I just want to check items with a specific surety.Id in the value. It doesn't seem like this should be too hard to do but like I said, I can't find any examples or good documentation on this.

I am using Angular 10 for both the core and material UI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `mat-list-option` `selected` input.

```
<mat-list-option  [selected]="condition">....
```

Comment: Thanks. What I meant is I need to select options from an existing array that isn't associated with the select list. I need to iterate through the select list and select options based on the [value] of the option. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

tmsbrndz pointed me in the right direction. I created the following function:

```
  isChecked(id): boolean {
        const exists = this.agentModel.AgentAgencyAndSureties.some(x => x.AgencyAndSuretyId == id);
        return exists;
  }
```

then added the selected attribute using the function:

```
<mat-selection-list color="primary" #suretyList formControlName="AgentAgencyAndSureties">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let surety of suretyNames" [value]="surety.Id" [selected]="isChecked(surety.Id)">
    {{surety.Id + " " + surety.SuretyName}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[selected]` attribute, because there's no information about form control support in this component (https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList)

Answer (score 0):

Import selection model from library:

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
```

Afterwards, declare selection:

```
private selection = new SelectionModel(true, []);
```

for mat-list-option selection, use [selected] property in HTML

HTML

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let business of subsidiaryBusinesses" [selected]="selection.isSelected(business)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); toggleSelection(business)">
              {{business.business_name}} ({{business.business_id}})
</mat-list-option>
```

Typescript

```
private selectedSubBusinesses: any = [];

toggleSelection(business) { //storing checked value in array
    let b_id = business.business_id;
    if(!this.selection.isSelected(business)) {
      if (this.selectedSubBusinesses.indexOf(b_id) === -1) {
        this.selectedSubBusinesses.push(b_id);
        this.selection.select(business);
      }
    } else {
      const index = this.selectedSubBusinesses.indexOf(b_id);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.selectedSubBusinesses.splice(index, 1);
        this.selection.deselect(business);
      }
    }
  }
```

Using this you can insert selected value in an array called "selectedSubBusinesses".

Data to select looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "business_id": "B1678884805",
        "business_name": "Google Inc",
        "business_abn": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "business_id": "B2967349224",
        "business_name": "Tutti Fruiti",
        "business_abn": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "business_id": "B4083124246",
        "business_name": "Boat Surf Company",
        "business_abn": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "business_id": "B520013933",
        "business_name": "Marvel Studio",
        "business_abn": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "business_id": "B788617867",
        "business_name": "Jerry and Tom Cartoons",
        "business_abn": "123456789"
    },
    {
        "business_id": "B80529544",
        "business_name": "Black Spidey Pty Ltd",
        "business_abn": "123456789"
    }
]
```